# How to profile meteorjs performance

Tags: javascript, meteor, profiling

I have a meteor.js app that offers chat rooms. Suddenly, when switching rooms, the chat loads (50 messages) extraordinarily slow. It takes multiple seconds for the 50 messages, I can see them popping in one by one. This is on my local machine, with a developer database with very few entries.

Now, the problem is much less visible in Chrome so I suspect it's a client-side issue. However, I don't know where to begin debugging this. My template is populated many times, each time with a few more messages than last.

Using the Safari profiler shows me that _.forEach, with a deep call tree of minimongo functions is consuming 32% of the total cpu time, with (idle) consuming 35% and (program) consuming 16%.

I am also looking into Kadira. It looks like it should be able to help me but the only thing I can make it show me is that "rooms" is the slowest cubscription with 12ms. Messages are not stored in Rooms, they are a separate collection with each message containing a room id.

I know this is a bit of a vague question but I am just wondering what the options are for performance profiling of Meteor apps in general, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently i faced the same issue and wanted to debug client side msgs and query updates.There is no official tool for client side as i think.
but you can debug as follows in local environment. I have used meteor 0.8.2 version.

1. You can track the client side minimongo updates and sockjs message transfers using minimongo and livedata meteor core packages.
2. Meteor does not allow to change the files in core packages. So copy and paste those two packages  folders from meteor core in to your project packages folder.
3. Now core packages will be replaced by your local packages. You can add console.log to the functions got high execution time.
4. As per my findings high heaps are triggered in following files.and i have logged points as per the code in paste bin.

   ```
    i. packages/livedata/livedata_connection.js : http://pastebin.com/zSxim0ij
    ii. packages/minimongo/minimongo.js : http://pastebin.com/FaP0Sfqs
    iii packages/livedata/sockjs-0.3.4.js : http://pastebin.com/kiWn0Ybx
   ```

you can simply replace the files with pastebin content if you are using the same meteor version.

To monitor the ddp msg transaction from client to outside you can use this nice tool. https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-ddp-analyzer

I guess kadira is working on creating a client side monitoring tool. Hope problems will be sorted then.